# change values of specific rows of a list of tibbles

Tags: r, list, tibble

im fairly new to R so Im still having some basic problems. Im working on a list of tibbles with 8760 tibbles. Each tibble has 5 rows of data with 420 columns. What I am trying to do is to change the first 40 values of a specific row for each tibble. How do I select the variable inside of the tibbles?

So I guess logically it will be something like the following. I know the syntax is wrong. Its just for you getting the idea:

```
data.list["data"] %>%
  data["pn"](0:40) = 0]
```

Id be glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

I now tried this:

```
daten_pn         <- readr::read_rds("./data/testdaten.rds") (8760 obs of 2 variables)
daten = daten_pn["data"] (selecting the first variable aka the tibbles)

set <- function(x) { x = x*0 return(x) } 

test = purrr::map(daten[["pn"]], set)
```

In oder to set them all to zero. But what im getting is an empty list.

here is a similar example:

```
a = list(
  mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-vs), 
  mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% sample_n(17)
)
> a
[[1]]
# A tibble: 32 x 10
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     0     4     4
# ... with 22 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 17 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  17.8     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
 2  15.2     8 304     150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     3     2
 3  15.5     8 318     150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     3     2
 4  21       6 160     110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 5  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
 6  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     5     2
 7  26       4 120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
 8  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1
10  15       8 301     335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
11  10.4     8 460     215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
12  17.3     8 276.    180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
13  21.4     6 258     110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
14  16.4     8 276.    180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
15  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
16  18.7     8 360     175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
17  21.5     4 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1
```

Now I want to change the values of one columne inside the tibbles. Like "set the first 5 values of cyl to 0 in both tibbles".

Best wishes

Comment: you can use `purrr::map` to iterate through the list, but consider making the data into one large tibble - often easier to process

Comment: Id prefer not to touch the structure because the data is inserted into more functions later on. I edited my post with my map approach, maybe you see my error?

Comment: Please include a reproducible example, probably with a small artificial dataset

Comment: I tried to recreate a similar problem and edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `purrr::map`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
a <- list(
  mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-vs), 
  mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% sample_n(17)
)

map(a, ~{
  .x[1:5, "cyl"] <- 0
  .x
  })
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 32 x 10
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       0  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     1     4     4
#>  2  21       0  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     0  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     0  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     0  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     0     4     4
#> # … with 22 more rows
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 17 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  27.3     0  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1
#>  2  13.3     0 350     245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4
#>  3  21.4     0 258     110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  4  21       0 160     110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  5  21.5     0 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1
#>  6  18.7     8 360     175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  7  26       4 120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
#>  8  18.1     6 225     105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  9  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#> 10  19.2     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> 11  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#> 12  17.8     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
#> 13  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     5     2
#> 14  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
#> 15  15.2     8 276.    180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
#> 16  19.2     8 400     175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     3     2
#> 17  19.7     6 145     175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>